# Accessing array levels in laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an array which shows below code after dump.

```
array:1[
    "123"=>array:3[
        "test1" => 12345
        "test2" => "test"
        "test3" => 123
    ]
]
```

I am trying to access each element in an html table and it's not showing my values. The code i am using is,

```
@foreach($testNumbers as $numbers)
<tr>
                <td>{{$numbers['123']->test1}}</td>  
                <td>{{$numbers['123']->test2}}</td> 
                <td>{{$numbers['123']->test3}}</td>  
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Can you please tell what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `123` is an array, not an object, so that syntax won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multidimensional array. Try using

```
{{$numbers['123']['test1']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is array of array (not of object) so you have to do like this:

```
    @foreach($testNumbers as $numbers)
    <tr>
                    <td>{{$numbers['test1']}}</td>  
                    <td>{{$numbers['test2']}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$numbers['test3']}}</td>  
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

OR

```
@foreach($testNumbers as $numbers)
        <tr>
            @foreach($numbers as $number)
                        <td>{{$number}}</td> 
            @endforeach
        </tr>
 @endforeach
```